# Why does my render look different when submitted from command line to a Linux cluster?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, command-line

If I render this scene using *Cycles* from my personal computer I get the scene on the left and if I run it from the command line on my university supercomputer, I get the image on the right. Both machines are running **Blender 2.82** and are using identical .blend files. I can't think of any reason that would cause them to differ. When I run the job from the command line, I use the command `blender -b bust.blend -o bust -E CYCLES -F PNG -f 1`, which has always worked for me in the past.

Here is a link to the blender file I am submitting:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ClZoyuQJwz9uob0ureN6rrZ6Sel688rC

[image]

Comment: Are you 100% sure they are the same blend file? I can't duplicate the issue when running the same command line options as you are. How are you sending the blend file over to the cluster?

Comment: I just checked again and am sure they are the same .blend file. I add it to the cluster by dragging and dropping with WinSCP. However, you are right. I just tried running it from my personal computer’s command line and it produces what I expected, meaning the command works. Therefore, it has to be something about the cluster. Is it possible that I get the problem because it was created on Windows and the cluster is Linux?

Comment: Can you post a factory default, default scene cube render from each. Are they different?

Comment: Since you said drag and drop, could it be that there are external files, that are missing when you only drag the blend file?

Comment: BatFinger, when I render the normal cube in each they came out identical, which means there must be a specific feature that the Linux cluster handles differently, right? So I kept removing settings and rerendering until it matched my machine’s render. This happened after I removed “volume scatter”! I don’t understand why, but it seems the cluster renders “volume scatter” as if the density was way higher.